# checking voltage range without a fixed reference voltage

Tags: voltage, comparison

I am trying to come up with a circuit to determine if my power supply voltage is within a specific range. For example, my nominal voltage is 3.3V but I want to make sure that the lowest voltage that I see is 3.15V and the highest voltage that I see is 3.45V. I have seen circuits on line that will check that a voltage is within a range. However these circuits depend on having a fixed reference voltage to compare against. In my case, the voltage I need to check is the power supply so I cannot create a reference voltage that depends on power supply since it is power supply that I am checking (chicken and egg thing). Does anyone have an idea on how I might accomplish this?

Thank you in advance,
Mike

Comment: yes, you use another voltage reference (e.g. LM431) in your circuit.

Comment: Use a stable voltage reference IC to produce a lower voltage than your supply, then use a simple resistor voltage divider from your supply to compare to the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a voltage reference IC that provides an independent voltage reference. It will be powered from your 3.3V power supply, which means that its reference voltage will be around 2.5V. You are trying to measure to an accuracy of around 4.5% so your voltage reference will need to be 1% or better to give an accurate reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a voltage reference IC, or even something as simple as a Zener diode. I'd recommend a dirt simple [shunt voltage reference](http://www.linear.com/products/shunt_voltage_references).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a voltage or current reference in order to compare to something fixed, LT1004-1.2 min. operating current is 8uA, TLV3401 OP's works down to 2.5V supply TLV3491 works with 1.8V supply no problem, you make a window comparator and you are set